# Approximation of `atan` function in fixed point

Tags: math, microcontroller, trigonometry, atmega, approximation

I must do some calculations that need to use trigonometric functions, and especially the `atan` one. The code will run on an Atmega328p, and for efficiency sake, I can't use `float`s: I'm using fixed point numbers. Thus, I can't use the standard `atan` function.

I which to have a function which take a value in fixed point format s16_10 (signed, 16 bits width, point in 10th position), and returns a s16_6 format. The input will be between 0 and 1 (so 0 and 2<sup>10</sup>), so the output, in degrees, will be between -45 and 45 (so -45 * 2<sup>6</sup> and 45 * 2<sup>6</sup>).

Let's say that Y is the fixed point, s16_6 representation of y, the real angle of the arc, and x such as `atan(x) = y`, and X the s16_10 representation of x. I start with approximating the `atan` function, from (0,1) to (-45,45) with a 4th degrees polynomial, and found that we can use:

```
y ~= 8.11 * x^4 - 19.67 * x^3 - 0.93 * x^2 + 57.52 * x + 0.0096
```

Which leads to:

```
Y ~= (8.11 * X^4)/2^34 - (19.62* X^3)/2^24 - (0.93 * X^2)/2^14 + (57.52*X)/2^4 + 0.0069 * 2^6
```

And here am I stuck... On the one hand, computing the `X^4` will lead to a 0 for one fifth of the definition interval, and on the other and the 2<sup>n4</sup><sub>n in {3, 2, 1}</sub> will often lead also to a zero value... How could I do ?

Comment: There probably is a typo in the last sentence ("and on the other and the 2n4 will often lead also") - please clarify. Also, when some intermediate result is 0, why is that a problem?

Comment: Also, are you obliged to use Taylor series? There is [CORDIC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CORDIC) which may be more efficient; I have never heard about Atmega328p so cannot determine which algorithm is better.

Comment: @anatolyg I've edited the answer for clarity! It's a problem in so far as the three first members are always zero... And I can't find an approximation which doesn't nullify the variable. I didn't know it was a Taylor serie, but I'll look CORDIC algorithm

Comment: Are you using `_Accum` or a custom type?

Comment: I'm using `typedef int16_t fixed16_p` where p is the position of the point

Comment: For the x^4 term, you could introduce `sqrt(8.11)` as the multiplier between the first and second squaring.

Comment: @anatolyg This isn't Taylor series of atan, it's a result of curve-fitting to atan with a polynomial.

Comment: It might be useful to know that atan(x) = (pi/2) - atan(1 / x). If your function is more accurate when abs(x) < 1 then you can take the inverse when it is > 1 and then subtract the result from (pi/2), or vice versa if abs(x) > 1 is more accurate. Limiting the input range to -1 to 1 might also enable you to use a lookup table

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some of the terms  being truncated to zero is not necessarily a disaster; this doesn't substantially worsen your approximation. I simulated your fixed precision setup in Matlab by rounding each term of the polynomial to the nearest integer:

```
q4 = @(X) round((8.11 * X.^4)/2^34);
q3 = @(X) -round((19.62* X.^3)/2^24);
q2 = @(X) -round((0.93 * X.^2)/2^14);
q1 = @(X) round((57.52*X)/2^4);
q0 = @(X) round(0.0069 * 2^6);
```

It's true that on the first fifth of the interval [0,2<sup>10</sup>] the terms q4, q3, q2 look rather choppy, and q4 is essentially absent.

[image: terms]

But these effects of rounding are of about the same size as the theoretical error of approximation of `atan` by your polynomial. Here is the plot where red is the difference (polynomial-atan) calculated *without* rounding to integers, and green is the difference (q4+q3+q2+q1+q0-atan):

[image: atanapprox]

As you can see, rounding does not make approximation much worse; in most cases it actually reduces the error by a happy accident.

---

I do notice that your polynomial systematically overestimates atan. When I fit a 4th degree polynomial to atan on [0,1] with Matlab, the coefficients are slightly different:

```
8.0927  -19.6568   -0.9257   57.5106   -0.0083
```

Even truncating these to two significant figures, as you did, I get a better approximation:

```
(8.09 * X^4)/2^34 - (19.66* X^3)/2^24 - (0.93 * X^2)/2^14 + (57.52*X)/2^4 - 0.0083 * 2^6
```

[image: betterpoly]

This time the truncation to integers does worsen things. But it is to be expected that the outcome of  a calculation where several intermediate results are rounded to integers will be off by +-2 or so. The theoretical accuracy of +-0.5, shown by this polynomial, cannot be realized with the given arithmetical tools.